# MEDIAPIPE failed run hello world from example

Tags: bazel, mediapipe

UBUNTU 20.04
bazel 3.0.0- (@non-git)
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14

Actually, the error itself:

```
dmitry@dmitry-pc:~/mediapipe$ bazel build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking:hand_tracking_cpu
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: SHA256 (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/master.zip) = f358144776d3dfc5a928ef32a0e4fbe93c99b55772d70cca77a6478e34d96aa7
DEBUG: Rule 'rules_foreign_cc' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments sha256 = "f358144776d3dfc5a928ef32a0e4fbe93c99b55772d70cca77a6478e34d96aa7"
DEBUG: Call stack for the definition of repository 'rules_foreign_cc' which is a http_archive (rule definition at /home/dmitry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dmitry/870728c32b519bd8ea9ab1059ef39614/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:296:16):
 - <builtin>
 - /home/dmitry/mediapipe/WORKSPACE:39:1
INFO: SHA256 (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/master.zip) = d1d266f0ee34a413af9e70b27354faddc2f300d873bcc388508901121e08aff4
DEBUG: Rule 'rules_cc' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments sha256 = "d1d266f0ee34a413af9e70b27354faddc2f300d873bcc388508901121e08aff4"
DEBUG: Call stack for the definition of repository 'rules_cc' which is a http_archive (rule definition at /home/dmitry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dmitry/870728c32b519bd8ea9ab1059ef39614/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:296:16):
 - <builtin>
 - /home/dmitry/mediapipe/WORKSPACE:33:1
ERROR: /home/dmitry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dmitry/870728c32b519bd8ea9ab1059ef39614/external/rules_cc/cc/private/rules_impl/cc_flags_supplier.bzl:28:21: rule() got unexpected keyword argument 'incompatible_use_toolchain_transition'
ERROR: While resolving toolchains for target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking:hand_tracking_cpu: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp': in /home/dmitry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dmitry/870728c32b519bd8ea9ab1059ef39614/external/rules_cc/cc/defs.bzl: Extension file 'cc/private/rules_impl/cc_flags_supplier.bzl' has errors
ERROR: Analysis of target '//mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking:hand_tracking_cpu' failed; build aborted: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp': in /home/dmitry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dmitry/870728c32b519bd8ea9ab1059ef39614/external/rules_cc/cc/defs.bzl: Extension file 'cc/private/rules_impl/cc_flags_supplier.bzl' has errors
INFO: Elapsed time: 12,845s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (2 packages loaded, 0 targe\
ts configured)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same error and the option `incompatible_use_toolchain_transition` doesn't seem to be supported in bazel version 3.0.0.

Try updating your bazel following their [manual](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install.html).

On more thing, the latest 3.5 version of bazel seem to have another [issue](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1094). So consider getting 3.4 version or apply the workaround in the Github issue.